# Problems with "Installation type" (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, system-installation

I'm installing Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa on a computer. I had removed all partitions with Gparted and made a 500MB fat32 partition with flag boot/esp because the hard drive had some problems making the computer not boot properly sometimes. It boots normally now, but when I go to install, it doesn't give me the option to wipe out the disk or anything, going straight to a partition table. This would be fine if it showed the hard drive, but it only shows /dev/sdb under devices, which is the USB I'm live booting with. /dev/sda is only there under "Device for boot loader installation". If I just press "Install now", it says "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu." /dev/sda is there on Gparted and it says there is 1.82 TB unallocated space.

I made sure to turn off Secure Boot, boot in BIOS mode not UEFI, and turn off "Fast Boot".

EDIT: switched SATA mode to AHCI and tried again with UEFI mode. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you select the partitions in the installer if you create the `/` and `/home` partitions manually with gparted?

Comment: You probably need to change the SATA mode to AHCI and, if you're creating an EFI partition then supposedly you want UEFI mode, not BIOS/Legacy mode. Actually some newer drives aren't even visible in Legacy mode. So, it's either one or the other, and you want AHCI and UEFI mode. It's really an absurd to try Legacy mode where it absolutely isn't necessary and counterproductive.

Comment: @Freddy I made two ext4 partitions with gparted but can't mount root or home because it's not installed yet

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I switched the SATA mode to AHCI and changed to UEFI mode but the problem's still there.

Comment: What problem exactly? Is the installer not letting you select the drive?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't ask me if I want to erase the Hard Drive and install Linux or the Something Else option. It goes straight to a partition table with only /dev/sdb as an available device which is the USB drive I'm live booting from.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make this hard drive an equivalent to sys your system in Linux.
Before you install Linux identify deva as "/" (root)
Also, the hard drive would run faster as ext4 instead of fat32.

Comment: I changed partitions to ext4 but it didn’t change much. The problem is that deva isn’t even shown in the devices during installation and I can’t do it on Gparted because root isn’t installed yet.

Comment: Run the HD in the computer not USB and install Linux Mint at the start tell Linux Install to fully format your HD and make a clean install. The install program should correct your GPART changes and add ROOT and Extensions to the existing HD.